# How to get number of row from Excel for two variable from two pages?

Tags: excel

I have 2 pages in Excel:
First page name: G1
Second page name: Calcul

I want that, in case S5 to get number of row where in page Istoric find the same value like that:

In g1 at B5 i have 8.02 and at S4 wk13. Sum(&) of them i have (wk138.02)

I want that, in page Istoric to find value (wk138.02) for two columns, in Column A i have wk13 and in Column B 8.02. Sum& of them (wk138.02)

In my page G1 i want value of row where find in Istoric (wk138.02)

My formula is but doesn't work:

```
=INDEX(Istoric!$C:$C, MATCH(S$4&"8.02",Istoric!$A:$A&"8.02", 0 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is very close to correct. Replace both instances of `"8.02"` to `$B5` and `Istoric!$B:$B`, respectively.

So the new formula will be:

```
=INDEX(Istoric!$C:$C, MATCH(S$4&$B5,Istoric!$A:$A&Istoric!$B:$B,0))
```

Also, be sure to enter the formula as an array formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when exiting cell edit mode.

Comment: In Evaluate Formula show me =INDEX(Istoric!$C:$C, MATCH("wk138.02","wk131.17",0) and is not correct, i want MATCH("wk138.02","wk138.02",0)

Comment: @Vladut - see my edit and make sure to enter as an **array** formula.

Comment: The same problem, get value for Page Istroric B number 1.17 not 8.02

Comment: In picture 2 you see on row 5 is 1.17 is that value i can.

Comment: @Vladut - make sure the cell references are accurate. I based my cell references on your picture 1 data and did my test against the formula. It returns 11.

Comment: =INDEX(Istoric!$C:$C, MATCH(S$4&B$5,Istoric!$A:$A&$B:$B,0)), is correct: ("wk138.02","wk138.02",0) but doesn't work to get my value :-?

Comment: @Vladut *it doesn't work to get my value*? what does this mean exactly? did you enter as array formula?

Comment: For that MATCH(S$4&B$5,Istoric!$A:$A&$B:$B,0) don't return a value, display me #VALUE

Comment: =INDEX(Istoric!$C:$C, #VALUE) that display in Show calculate steps

Comment: @vladut - just enter it as an array formula in the cell and it will work.

Comment: Ok i can the match is not ok

Comment: @Vladut - at this point, I don't know what else to say, I tested it **exactly** as you have shown in your data screenshot above and it works. I can't tell what you are doing fully to test it, but all you need to do is copy the formula I wrote above into cell `S5`and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` it will show `11` as a result.